# How can I make some addition in Liste/Arrays (Python)

Tags: python, arrays

I'm learning Liste / Matrice in Python and I would like to make some addition in Liste. Let me explain, in the exemple, in the Table "exam_liste" the second position (1 in python) I want to add +2 and refresh the table, I don't want to insert anything, I want to make an addition directly in the Liste and in my exemple it doesn't working.

Anyone can explain me this ?

```
 ote = 1

 exam_liste = [None] * 5
 print(exam_liste)


 exam_liste.insert(1,note)
 print(exam_liste)

 exam_liste.insert(1,exam_liste[1]+2)
 print(exam_liste)

 >>> [None, None, None, None, None]
 >>> [None, 1, None, None, None, None]
 >>> [None, 3, 1, None, None, None, None]
```

I was waiting like : [None, **3**, None, None, None, None, None]

Comment: You want to map things: `map(lambda x: x if x is None else x + 2, list)`.
Or just use  list[index] += value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add to an integer in the list, you need to access the item and add to it, not insert another item into the list:

```
exam_liste[1] = exam_list[1] + 2
```

By using `insert`, you're adding an entirely new element to the list. If you want to modify an item from the list, you have to grab it with its index. But obviously you will have to insert an integer into the list before you can add to that integer. So after your list is created:

```
exam_liste.insert(1,note)
exam_liste[1] = exam_list[1] + 2
```

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear, but I was assuming he still would have inserted a number into the first position before trying to add to it. Seems logical

Answer (score 0):

This is the definition of insert:

```
list.insert(index, elem)
```

Which it means, insert the element at the given index, shifting elements to the right.
So when you write `exam_liste.insert(1,exam_liste[1]+2)` it will add `exam_liste[1]+2` which is `3` to the second element of previous list which was `[None, 1, None, None, None, None]`

Rather than using  `exam_liste.insert(1,exam_liste[1]+2)`, use the following line:

```
exam_liste[1] +=2
```